# Не могу получить данные из sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Нужно получить данные из бд и переписать их на переменные например. Не работает запрос query2. [image: Скрин ошибки]

```
     try
                {
                    string query = "SELECT (idStudent) FROM [Group] WHERE NumberOfGroup="+textBox2.Text+"";
                    string query2 = "SELECT (SELECT Surname,Name FROM [GR22] WHERE Surname=@surname AND Name=@name) FROM [Group]";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand(query2, sqlConnection);
                    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;
                    SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    parameter1.Value = textBox3.Text;
                    parameter2.Value = textBox1.Text;
                    sqlCommand2.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
                    sqlCommand2.Parameters.Add(parameter2);
                    sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand2.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    string answerN = "";
                    MessageBox.Show(sqlDataReader.FieldCount.ToString());
                    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                    {

                        answerN = sqlDataReader["Name"].ToString();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(answerN);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { MessageBox.Show("Error #" + ex); }
                sqlConnection.Close();
```

Скриншоты бд прилагаю[image: таблица1]

[image: таблица2]

Comment: Что вы хотели получить задав такой `SELECT (SELECT Surname,Name FROM [GR22] WHERE Surname=@surname AND Name=@name) FROM [Group]` запрос? И вы уж определитесь используете ли вы параметризованные запросы или лоховские типа такого `WHERE NumberOfGroup="+textBox2.Text+""`. B в блоке try зачем MessageBoxы пихать? Может тогда всю программу в один try/catch поместить?

Comment: в МБокс я кидаю для проверки данных есть там что то или нет. запрос query я буду переделывать потом а помощи прошу только по 2. Через query 2 я хотел сделать выборку из таблицы GR22 и сравнить с данными из таблицы Group есть ли там такая запись

Comment: Вам надо переделать запрос 2, т.к. после SELECT должны следовать либо названия столбцов из таблицы Group либо значения агрегирующих методов типа COUNT(), но никак не результат вложенного запроса.

Comment: Для проверки промежуточных данных надо использовать `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();` и смотреть в окошке Output какие сообщения прибежали.